# Identity for Landau symbols (little $o$)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was wondering if the following is true:

If $f=g+o(x)$, then $o(f)=o(g)$.

Here, $f=f(x)$, $g=g(x)$.

Comment: What is $o(f) = o(g)$ supposed to mean here?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I take it as $\forall h, (h=o(f) \Leftrightarrow h=o(g))$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not true. 
*With the remark that it's usually a very good idea to specify **where** the asymptotics are taken (i.e., the point $a\in [-\infty,\infty]$).*

Now, take $f,g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x^4$. Consider the asymptotics at $0$: certainly,
$$
f(x) = g(x) + o(x) 
$$
as desired. Yet, we do have $x^3 = o(f(x))$ (at $0$, but definitely **not** $x^3=o(g(x))$.

Comment: Thank you for answer, clement c. But if we have, $f=g+o(g)$ is it then true that $o(f)=o(g)$?

Comment: @PeterM In that case, yes. Can you show it from the definition?

Comment: yes, because $f=g+o(g)$ equivalent $\frac{f}{g}\to 1$. Then just insert definition. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem (be careful with the equivalence you just wrote -- it is only true if $g$ never cancels). As for the rest: if your question has been settled, consider accepting an answer by clicking on the $\color{green}\checkmark$.

Comment: To the downvoter: care to explain why?

Answer (score -1):

The writing ''$o(f)=o(g)$'' does not make any sense: the symbol "little o" is not defined like an operator on functions, but only as $f(x)=o(g(x))$ for $x\rightarrow x_0$, meaning that the quotient of $f$ by $g$ has limit zero as $x\rightarrow x_0$, and that is it. So your equality does not make any sense.

To be more precise, and to clarify something which is not completely clear in the book, something that people often overlook, or simply do not know at all is that, from a logical point of view, when we define $f(x)=o(g(x))$in Mathematics what is defined it is not really the *symbol* ''$o$'', but the *symbol* ''$=o$'', and this is the reason why equations of the kind you wrote simply do not make sense.

The same thing is true for all the other ''order of growth'' symbols like $O$, $\sim$, etc. What we define are not these symbols per se, but the notions ''$=O $ '', ''$=\Theta$'', and so on.

Comment: It does make sense (if specified where the asymptotics are taken). You can use it (and it is often done) to denote the set of functions that are $o(f)$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation I reckon the OP when that, or, easier to interpret: "$h=o(f)$ at $a$ iff $h=o(g)$ at $a$."

Comment: And after your edit, regarding the last paragraph: "Additionally, the notation $O(g(x))$ is also used to denote the set of all functions $f(x)$ that satisfy the relation $f(x) = O(g(x))$ In this case we write $f(x)\in O(g(x))$." (from the definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition)). (And what is the notation $=\sim$ you mention?)

Comment: @ClementC. I see your point, but I think it is a typical case of a bad choice of symbols, for the reasons I explained above. The use of the symbols "$f=o(g)$", "$f=O(g)$, $f=\Theta(g)$, etc., is often cause of great confusions and of subtle mistakes. I remember a lecture of E. Bombieri on this, where he cautioned to use these symbols, and told us that in many papers he had  found serious mistakes which originated by a wrong use of these symbols. That's why the notation $o(f)=o(g)$ should be avoided at all in my opinion.

Comment: I agree that being careful and consistent with the notations is important (and the number of aberrations related to a bad use of Landau notations is... frightening). But in this case, the OP's question is relatively simple to interpret, and can completely be understood when considering the notations as indicating classes of functions (which is a rather standard use). Dismissing the question on these grounds is not (in my opinion) justified.